# Specifying allowed arguments in templates

Tags: c++, templates, generics, sfinae, static-assert

Can I specify exactly what kind of arguments a template can receive? For example, I'd like to create a template that can only be instantiated with classes that are or extend class `A`. In Java, generics support this with:

```
class B<T extends A> { }
```

Can something similar be achieved with templates in C++?

```
template <typename T (?)> class B { }
```

Comment: You can do this via `static_assert` and `std::is_same` (for A) and `std::is_base_of` (for derived). I'll write up an example. I think `std::enable_if` might do it, too, but I can't say I've used it.

Comment: Here's the [example](http://ideone.com/o7Vmg). You can change around what's passed in (`a` and `b` work, but `c` doesn't). If you don't have C++11 (for the static assert), I feel `std::enable_if` might help, but I'm not exactly sure how to use it off the top of my head. It also won't provide a clear error message.

Comment: @chris, I don't seem to have the `type_traits` header file. Where should I look for `static_assert`, `std::is_base_of` and `std::enable_if`?

Comment: No type_traits? That's odd, as it's a standard header. It should be with all of the others. `static_assert` is C++11-only, and it actually seems `enable_if` is too, heh. `is_base_of` is, too, so I guess C++11 is required for this, because I can't think of any other smooth way to do it. In order to use that, you need a compiler with support for those features and the `-std=c++11` option.

Comment: @chris, I see... So this is a fairly recent addition?

Comment: I found out that boost actually has its own versions of `enable_if` and `is_base_of` that you can use in C++03. The others are part of C++ as of last year, so yes, they're pretty new compared to the C++03 stuff. Metaprogramming really evolved through that addition. Boost is something that C++03 users almost can't go without, and C++11 users still really benefit from, too. I've managed to just ignore it's existence while standard C++ copies their ideas.

Comment: @chris, from what I understand, C++11 is heavily inspired by boost, so it's likely that most C++11 features are actually boost features. So if I want to keep the program portable (since C++11 support is pretty bad at the time), I need to either use boost or not support this functionality?

Comment: I might be missing a different, more hackish way of doing this, but I don't think there's much else besides C++11 or boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

First, through a hidden dummy template parameter that uses `std::enable_if` with a `std::is_base_of<A, T>::value` as condition. If the latter expression evaulates to `false`, then the nested `type` does not exist in `std::enable_if`. If you were using this on overloaded functions, SFINAE then means "substitution failure is not an error", and the overload in question would be removed from the set of viable functions. HOwever in this situation, there is no other class template to match your call, and then you do get a compile-time error.

SFINAE is a very subtle mechanism and easy to get wrong. E.g. if you have multiple class specializations with different SFINAE conditions, you have to make sure that they are all non-overlapping, or else you get an ambiguity.

Second, you can do a simple `static_assert` with a `std::is_base_of<A,T>::value` inside the body of the class. The advantage of this method is that you also specify a more readable error message compared to the SFINAE method. A disadvantage is that you always get an error, and you cannot silently suppress this particular template and select another one. But overall I think this method is recommended in your case.

```
#include<type_traits>

class A {};
class C: public A {};
class D {};

// first alternative: SFINAE on hidden template parameter
template
<
    typename T, 
    typename /* dummy */ = typename std::enable_if< 
        std::is_base_of<A, T>::value
    >::type
>
class B
{
};

// second alternative: static_assert inside class
template
<
    typename T
>
class E
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, "A should be a base of T");
};

int main()
{
    B<A> b1;
    B<C> c1;
    //B<D> d1; // uncomment this line to get a compile-time error

    E<A> b2;
    E<C> c2;
    //E<D> d2; // uncomment this line to get a compile-time error

    return 0;
}
```

As was pointed out in the comments,  you can use either a decent C++11 compiler (VC++ 2010 or later, gcc 4.5 or later) or the Boost or TR1 libraries to get the `<type_traits>` functionality. Note however that the `std::is_base_of<A, A>::value` evaluates to `true`, but the old `boost::is_base_of<A, A>::value` used to evalute to `false`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `static_assert` and `is_base_of`:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T> class D {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, "must be derived from A");
};
```

Or you can use `enable_if`:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T, typename = void> class D;
template<typename T> class D<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value>::type> {
};
```

For C++03 you can use boost; `is_base_of` from [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html), `static_assert` from [Boost.StaticAssert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html), `enable_if` from [Boost.EnableIf](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html).